# How to take curly brace to end of previous line

Tags: vim

I see many codes like following on the net:

```
public static void read()
    {
        using (StreamReader m_StreamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\myCsv.Csv")) 
        {
            while (m_StreamReader.Peek >= 0) 
            {
                string m_Str = m_StreamReader.ReadLine;
                string[] m_Splitted = m_Str.Split(new char[] { "," });
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}={1}", m_Splitted[0], m_Splitted[1]));
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I want to convert above to following:

```
public static void read() {
        using (StreamReader m_StreamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\myCsv.Csv")) {
            while (m_StreamReader.Peek >= 0) {
                string m_Str = m_StreamReader.ReadLine;
                string[] m_Splitted = m_Str.Split(new char[] { "," });
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}={1}", m_Splitted[0], m_Splitted[1]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Hence starting curly brace is taken to the end of previous line. How can this be done programmatically in Vim? It tried but though I can pick up starting curly brace but could not manage to take it to end of previous line.

Note: above code is from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/625216/Reading-CSV-files-in-Csharp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joining the next line to the current line is done with `:help J` in normal mode or `:help :join` in command-line mode.

Joining the current line to the previous line is done in normal mode by moving the cursor to the previous line with `-` and then joining with `J`. In command-line mode, you would use `-`, short for `.-1` ("current line number minus one"), as `:h address` for `:join`: `:-j`, which mirrors the normal mode method quite well.

To do this on the whole buffer, you need a way to execute a given command on every isolated opening brace. This is done with `:help :g`:

```
:g/^\s*{\s*$/-j
```

Breakdown:

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on every line matching `<pattern>`,
- `^\s*{\s*$` matches lines with a single opening braces and optional leading and trailing whitespace,
- `-j` joins the current line with the line above.

But the result is not correctly indented anymore so you will need something like the following command to fix the mess:

```
gg=G
```

Breakdown:

- `gg` moves the cursor to line 1,
- `=G` re-indents every line from the cursor to the last line, see `:help =`.

That said, switching from one coding style to another seems like something that should be done with a dedicated tool rather than with general text editing.

Comment: Very well explained but `gg=G` is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The desired output looks strikingly similar to the [ratliff style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Ratliff_style). If that's correct, `astyle` is one formatter that supports this particular style and this solution will be more robust than making changes manually.

You can wrap it in your own command as follows:

```
command! -buffer Fmt let winsaved = winsaveview() | execute '%! astyle --style=ratliff' | if v:shell_error > 0 | silent undo | endif | call winrestview(winsaved)
```